# How can I delay checkbox postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have an ASP.NET page with JavaScript.
I have some checkboxes and I want to give the user time to check and uncheck more then one box before the postback... so when the user tick/untick a check box the postback happens after 5 seconds. How can I do this? tried different methods found online but all incomplete or wrong.

Comment: Maybe link us the methods you have tried so far and explain what went wrong / why it did not work. That way we can see if you made a mistake somewhere or another appoach is needed.

Comment: Javascript timer? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the AutoPostBack property of the checkboxes to false. Use a button that performs the Postback for you (e.g. call that the 'Save changes' button)

That gives you all the flexibility you need. You may even insert a JavaScript that performs the ButtonClick automatically after xx seconds.

Comment: Further to this you could hide the button and only call it programmatically, this gives the impression that you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. You can hide its visibilty with css, like visibility:hidden. If you use the Visibility property in codebehind, the button won't be rendered, if it's visibility it set to false